# How to minimise the multiple XML and javascript in Android studio

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

My goal is to have a single activity that accommodates all the Java logic while maintaining the shared structure. This would not only streamline development but also make future additions more efficient.

I'm seeking advice on best practices or design patterns that would help achieve this consolidation effectively. Any insights or examples on dynamically managing content within a single activity would be greatly appreciated.

I've experimented with creating multiple XML activities and their corresponding Java scripts for my Android app. The activities share a common structure, differing only in content, and navigation is facilitated by buttons.

My expectation was to find a way to minimize redundancy and streamline the development process. I'm exploring the possibility of consolidating all Java logic into a single activity while preserving the shared structure. This approach would not only enhance efficiency but also simplify future additions.

I'm looking for guidance on design patterns or best practices that could help achieve this consolidation effectively. Any insights or examples related to dynamically managing content within a singular activity would be incredibly valuable.

Comment: `Java logic` - so, tag `java`, not `javascript`